# React router: How to import functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, react-router, export

I want to export the function, `welcome()`, from my `App` file to another file, `AddKit`, which is one of the file defining a page of my application. I tried various means but each time I have this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'welcome' of undefined
```

App.js :

```
class App extends Component {
  welcome(){
    return 'TrialOne';
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.web3) {
      return <div>Loading Web3, accounts, and contract...</div>;
    }
    return (
       <BrowserRouter>
        <nav>
          <Navigation/>
            <Switch>
             <Route path="/" component={Home} exact/>
             <Route path="/addKit" component={AddKit} exact/>
           </Switch>
        </nav> 
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

AddKit.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import welcome from '../App.js'

const AddKit = () => {
    return (
       <div>
          <h1>AddKit</h1>
          <p>AddKit page body content</p>
       </div>
    );
}
 
export default AddKit;
```

So, how do I properly export and use this function inside my AddKit file?

Comment: Is that the full code? Because the braces don't match; if you have an error in the `App.js` file that we can't see, I'm not sure the answer below will work (but it's the correct answer, assuming correct code)

Comment: @yen No it's not the full code. The missing brace comes surely from the missing class `App extends Components `. Thanks for telling me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define welcome function as below:

`export const Welcome = () => {return ()}`

and then import it this way:

`import { Welcome } from '../App.js'`

Comment: Do I add `export const Welcome = () => anything` below export default App ? And if I understood I change the anything with what I want to return right ?

Comment: No, not necessarily below the export default; I will make the edit.

Comment: and yes, instead of anything, you need to add return expression.

Comment: after importing the welcome function; use it as welcome() in the AppKit.js to have the returned value.

Comment: I'm happy it helped you. Good luck :D

Comment: Just a little last question, can I use this method if I want to send the value of a variable from app to addkit ?